# C# Technique - Getting Constant Values By String

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, constants

Is there any good way to convert strings like "xlSum", "xlAverage", and "xlCount" into the value they have under Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlConsolidationFunction?

I guess reflection would be slow (if its possible). There are about 10 of these constant values. I was trying to avoid a large switch statement if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an enum so you should be able to use

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

XlConslidationFunction func = (XlConsolidationFunction)
                               Enum.Parse( typeof(XlConsolidationFunction),
                                           stringVal );
```

Comment: You'll need a cast between "=" and "Enum", but +1

Comment: thx.  I never use the as syntax but I was trying to make it prettier for the post.

Comment: Enum.Parse() - guess I never stumbled upon this before. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of switch you can always use a `Dictionary<string, ...>` and fill it once when the application starts